# How to detect HLS video is for Live, VOD or Event in Exoplayer android

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I have integrated android [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) in my application. I have to detect the HLS (.m3u8) stream received is for Live or VOD or Event, so depending on that controller has to be modified for the player. I have only one instance of player so that should handle all the supported media like vod or live or event.
I am looking for some debug points to know working of m3u8 parser in exoplayer so that I can able to receive this parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use below code to play .m3u8 file:-**

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

//Create the player using ExoPlayerFactory
videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context,trackSelector);

Handler mHandler = new Handler();

String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "Exo Player");

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true);

HlsMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl),dataSourceFactory, 1800000,mHandler, null);

if (mediaUrl != null) {
    videoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Live vs Event differentiation is not supported, yet. For Live vs Event you can check the current Timeline, but that's not HLS specific. For distinguish a live stream from a vod one by querying the player's duration after it is prepared. Live streams will return UNKNOWN_TIME, where-as vod streams will return the known duration of the stream.

Comment: Exoplayer 2 has been supported for Event streaming also.